# Limit FTP/WebDAV file upload size in Alfresco

Tags: ftp, limit, alfresco, webdav

I must prevent anyone from uploading to Alfresco files bigger than 100 MB, be it via FTP or via WebDAV.

How to do?

Feel free to propose solutions for only FTP or only WebDAV.

*(here I don't care about the Share UI, which is the topic of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933566/how-can-i-set-a-size-limit-for-files-uploaded-in-alfresco-4-2-c))*

Comment: So, if I understand well, you want to be able to upload file bigger than 100Mb on other channels than FTP or WebDAV ? Or having a system preventing every upload bigger than 100Mb is ok ?

Comment: @Akah: It is OK to prevent big file from being uploaded by *any* protocol (CMIS, CIFS, etc) in addition to FTP and WebDAV.

Comment: Did you find an solution for this one ?

Comment: @Akah: I am still looking for an optimal solution, I will need this before mid-2018.

Answer (score 0):

If it's OK for any behaviour, you might be able to create a [custom rule on file upload and apply an action](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/tasks/library-folder-rules-define.html) (which would throw a business error for example) :

Comment: Indeed that's an option! New sites will be created/deleted every few days by administrators not familiar with Alfresco, so I would like to keep site configuration very easy... I believe site templates might be used to automatically configure this rule on any new site :-)

Comment: Yes you can. I also guess that you might put this rule on the global sites folder (not tested, might be a solution).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this https://docs.alfresco.com/community/concepts/dev-extensions-share-module-dynamic-configuration.html. You can customize the file size

```
    `<configurations>
        <config evaluator="string-compare" condition="DocumentLibrary" replace="true">
           <file-upload>
              <adobe-flash-enabled>false</adobe-flash-enabled>
              <in-memory-limit>262144000</in-memory-limit>
              <maximum-file-size-limit>0</maximum-file-size-limit>
           </file-upload>
        </config>
     </configurations>`
```

Replace zero with desired size in bytes

Comment: These are Share settings, they do not apply to FTP/WebDAV.